# Mysql multiple left join on same table for grouping results

Tags: mysql, left-join

**Table** 
[This stable stores some history of address changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z66L3.png)

```
Id  Name    Address        Group Id
1   AAA      Primary          1
2   BBB      Secondary        1
3   CCC      Primary          1
4   DDD      Secondary        1
5   EEE      Primary          1
6   FFF      Primary          2
7   GGG      Secondary        2
8   HHH      Primary          3
9   III      Secondary        4
10  JJJ      Secondary        1
```

**Result**  [I need a result like beleow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znSTk.png)

```
Primary Address Secondary Address
AAA                  BBB
CCC                  DDD
EEE                  JJJ
FFF                  GGG
HHH                  NULL
NULL                 III
```

Is it possible to achieve this result with mysql joins

Comment: Normally you can pivot only problem is you don't same to have a column within a group where you can indentify the correct position so the answer is No

Comment: Will the row of a secondary address be always after the Primary address ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `case when` expression

```
select case when address='Primary' then name end as PrimaryAddress,
case when address='Secondary' then name end as SecondaryAddress
from tablename
```

Comment: I have tried the same but it doesn't give me primary and secondary in the same row. Either primary or secondary is coming null with this case option.